# how to display a dropped image file in browser on a canvas or as a HtmlImageElement (<img>)

Tags: javascript, browser

i actually wondering why the only way of doing this is taking the binary data from the file, base64-encode it and then feed this encoded String into an  Tag / HtmlImageElement

Either as plain HTML

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxxx...">
```

or via javascript

```
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL( droppedFile ); // this converts the binary data from the file into base64
reader.onloadend = () => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = reader.result;
    img.onloadend = () => { 
        console.log(`image ${droppedFile.name} loaded.`);
    }  
}
```

A weird performance: Data is base64-encoded, which turns an 1MB Image into 1.33MB String (this really takes time), then placed inside the Image Element, just to be decoded again (which again takes time) to be displayed ...

Why is that?

There is really no way to use TypedArray's (UInt8Arrays) instead?

And where exactly does the browser check for the file type and decodes the image data, width and height of lets say a dropped jpg file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know another way that is most likely faster. You directly take the File and convert it to ObjectURL.

That way:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input"),
    img = document.querySelector("img")

input.addEventListener("change", () => {
    if (input.files.length) {
        const file = input.files[0],
            url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file)

        img.src = url
    } else {
        img.src = ""
    }
})
```

```html
<input type="file" />
<img src="" />
```

Comment: this is probably the best approach for now, but it still converts to base64 String forth and back, which is the true performance killer here.

Comment: @bugpulver I'm not aware of that. For me, it makes the file available in a link, but it doesn't go through the base64 transformation.

Answer (score 0):

In the Browser-Javascript world, there is a way to skip the forth-and-back-base64-conversion using the [`ImageDecoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageDecoder/decode#browser_compatibility) for such cases, but its experimental and not supported by Firefox by now.

So it seems like there is no way to skip this conversion-issue on dropped images in production.

Luckily, i'm actually building a lot of WASM stuff in rust, enabling me to use an [image-crate](https://crates.io/crates/image) to decode the image-data from jpg to bitmap by myself. Lets see if i get this up and running ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).